# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the email of the currently logged in user which I will then use to get the name data field from the document corresponding to this user. However, I keep getting this error. Any idea on how to fix this issue would be highly appreciated.

Additionally, whenever I make any change in regard to the email issue, I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.db.collection is not a function`

And when I refresh the page it returns back to the error in the title.

```
const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
const userEmail = user.email;
let clubName;

db.collection("users").where("email", "==", userEmail).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    let data = doc.data();
    clubName = data.name;
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
console.log("THE DATA YOU ARE LOOKING FOR: " + clubName);
const q = query(collection(db, "requests"), where("SendTo", "==", clubName));
```

NOTE: in the code above I am using 2 different firebase databases one called users which has the fields {email, name, password, job} and the other called requests which have the following fields {From, SendTo, type, content, header}

Comment: Did you try logging `user`?

Comment: `auth.currentUser` is `null`

Comment: @Konrad how do I fix that?

Comment: @tstrmn can you emphasize? sorry I am a beginner

Comment: I have no idea how your `getAuth` looks like

Comment: @Konrad it is imported from firebase/auth

Comment: Then the initialised app should be passed as the first argument, shouldn't it? (haven't used firebase in years so not sure)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I just tried that, still gives me the same error

Comment: @alwaysneedhelp1901 Well, if `auth.currentUser` is `null`, you'll receive the same error. You should check if `currentUser` is `null` and if it is, do something else like send to a login page, show a login modal or something.

Comment: What firebase version are you using? If it is 9+ db.collection doesn't work anymore, you have to use doc, getDoc etc. Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_1

Comment: @Marios ok I used getDoc(collection(db, "users")).where..... (rest is like what i wrote in my code) now I am getting this error: Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Xc', but it was: a custom ta object

Comment: It's not only this, everything else need to change. You can't call .where on there. There is a query() function now.

Do 
const myDoc= await getDoc(collection(db, "users"))
const q = query(myDoc, where("email", "==", userEmail)) and then the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth.currentUser` might be null because the auth object has not finished initializing.

Try using `onAuthStateChanged` assuming you are using firebase v9.

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
   // User is signed in

  } else {
    // User is signed out  

  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It now works, I no longer get null for email when I refresh the page